# How can I customize the output of this .groupby operation done on this DataFrame in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, output, pandas-groupby

I am working with a DataFrame to create a frequency distribution by counting the three types of values in one column. In this example, I'm counting and displaying each person's "personal status". When I execute the code, all of the other columns are displayed with the count repeated in each column. I'd like the count of each value to be displayed once without a column heading. What do I need to do to accomplish this?

`creditData.groupby(['Personal_Status']).count()`

Here's an image of my output:
[Current Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JJ5uZ.png)

Edit: Here's what I'd like the output to look like: [Desired Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xB4fd.png)

Comment: Could you please describe your expected output a little bit closer, like giving an example based on your picture

Comment: And your original dataframe

Comment: @FlorianD. So, instead of displaying the frequencies repeated under all of the columns, as it's shown in the picture, I'd just like the frequencies displayed once under one nameless column. I'll attach a photo showing what I want it to look like

Comment: @FlorianD. My dataframe was created from a CSV file with 425 records representing people sorted into 15 columns such as Job type, credit standing, credit history, housing type, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's recommended in the documentation is to use `Named aggregation`

```
import pandas as pd
animals = pd.DataFrame(
     {
         "kind": ["cat", "dog", "cat", "dog"],
         "height": [9.1, 6.0, 9.5, 34.0],
         "weight": [7.9, 7.5, 9.9, 198.0],
     }
 )

animals.groupby('kind').agg(**{
    '':('height','count')
})
```

This will get you

```
kind    
cat 2
dog 2
```

For reference https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html (search for named aggregation)

Answer (score 0):

This would probably do the trick:

```
(
    creditData[["Age", "Personal_Status"]]
    .groupby(["Personal_Status"]).count()
    .rename({"Age": ""}, axis="columns"
)
```

Comment: thank you for this! It worked to eliminate the other columns. Is there a way to have no "header" for the column? Or do I have to specify a column, such as "Age" in your code provided?

Comment: @c.moon could you accept the answer then maybe?

Comment: just a visual preference, but it's not necessary. Thank you for your help!

Comment: When you select only one other column besides your garget groupby column, you will be only left with one column with your aggregated values. To remove the header visually, maybe also look at @John Kitchin's answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a new column with no name (empty string here), then select that one and remake the result to a frame to look like what you want.

```
creditData[''] = 1
creditData.groupby(['Personal_Status']).count()[''].to_frame()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `creditData["Personal_Status"].value_counts()` would be the best solution